# Compile errors in new Android project in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm using Eclipse for build an Android project. when I try to open bellow item :

```
file --> new --> Android Application Project
```

Then when the project is built a series `errors` displayed :

[image]

I am a beginner in this regard and thank you for your help.

Comment: your "appcompat_v7" project is closed. Do open it first.

Comment: change `target` to android-21 in your project properties file

Comment: Yes, I open it but this error displayed in console: `[2015-06-23 16:30:22 - appcompat_v7] Project has no project.properties file! Edit the project properties to set one.`

Comment: @Karan Mer `Unable to resolve target 'android-21'`

Comment: make sure you have updated your android-SDK , ADT plugin and you have downloaded platform for which you are developing

Answer (score 1):

Open AppCompactv7 and add as library on your project

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your appcompat_v7 project. Delete the existing project one in the workspace and re-import it from

> \sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat

After that try cleaning the project.

> Project -> select Clean -> select the project.

Comment: I removed appcompat_v7 but I can't re-import this. Though the `android-support-v7-appcompat.jar` imported in `project properties>java build path> libraries`, but I can't Add this from  `project properties>Android>Add` because this not exists in `project selection` window!

Comment: import the library project from this location **\sdk\extras\android\support\v7\appcompat**. Then it will appear in project selection window.

Answer (score 0):

1 - Make sure library project(appcompat_v7) is **open** & is **proper referenced** (added as library) in your application project.To do this follow this steps: right click in your project -> "**Properties - Android - Add**"

2 - Delete android-support-v4.jar from your project's libs folder(**if jar is present**).

3 - Appcompat_v7 must have android-support-v4.jar & android-support-v7-appcompat.jar inside it's libs folder. (**If jars are not present copy them from /sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompat/libs** folder of your installed android sdk location)

4- Check whether ActionBarActivity is properly imported. (In your case this is right)

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;

[Here](http://www.righthandedmonkey.com/2013/09/how-to-run-android-support-library.html) is a good example of how to create a project in Eclipse using v7 Support Library

Finally because you are a beginner I'll recommend you to use Android Studio as it is the official environment for developing for Android. Configuring the SDK can be quite a pain in Eclipse. You can also take advantage of the Gradle dependency system and simply specify which libraries you would like to use and Android Studio will automatically fetch the jars from online remotes as required. I think its the future of Android Application Development.